# FQL facebook query language: how can i query the list of friends of a specific user that has my application installed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

When a user logs in to my facebook application, i want to show him a list of all of his friends that has my application installed.

can I use FQL to query who's of his friends have my application installed? and if so how ?

thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually, you can do pull list of friends who installed an app through FQL.

```
SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE is_app_user  AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this also, if is_app_user=1 then its app user.

> NSString *query =
>       @"SELECT uid, name, pic_square,is_app_user FROM user WHERE uid IN "
>       @"(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 25)";