# FQL : Retrieving a list of All User's Friends that Have Authorized My App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have found various FQL querying solutions on other posts here on stackoverflow ([Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398385/fql-facebook-query-language-how-can-i-query-the-list-of-friends-of-a-specific-u), [Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060238/facebook-application-count-friends-registered)) to extract a list of all a user's friends that have authorized my application, but when I try to demo these on the  [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), I get the following query parser error:

```
{
      "error": {
            "message": "(#601) Parser error: unexpected end of query.",
            "type": "OAuthException"  
      }
}
```

Here's the exact syntax I'm using for my query (taken from "Post 1" listed above)...

```
fql?q=SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE is_app_user  AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest adding `=1` to your `is_app_user` (*I guess it will work without it too*):

```
SELECT uid, name, pic_square
FROM user 
WHERE is_app_user=1 AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

At one point, this was broken in the [explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), but as of June 2014, Facebook had fixed it. (*Read this [comment](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/579/?fb_comment_id=fbc_10150330925594072_19196152_10150331528679072).*)

Comment: Ah so this will actually work in my deployed application, I just can't test it via the Graph Explorer?

Comment: @nomizzz yeah I guess so! Best thing to do it to try it outside the explorer ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it will take some time for me to test this out as I need to wrap the relevant Facebook Connect functions in GWT (I wrapped the login methods and appropriate callbacks already, just not the FQL calls) before proceeding.  I'll let you know how it goes once I do.  Thanks for the help thus far!

Comment: Right on the money.  Implemented the query directly in my application and it works flawlessly.  A shame that the Graph Explorer isn't more reliable, I'm just thankful you tightened up that query before I spent hours debugging it.

Comment: You are welcome! The Graph Explorer is a great tool and definitely reliable....but at the end it's a tool made by human :-)